# update nested object inside object in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am looking for the best solution to update the key values inside the nested objects in angular.

The solution which I know is manually running 2 for loops and updating each property.

below is what I  have tried and what I want to achieve.

Are there any options to avoid ending up running 2 loops?

I was thinking to use map option inside the loop but not getting what I expected.

```js
obj1 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":26
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   }
]


Result = 

obj1 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "newlabel":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "newid":16,
            "extraparam1":null
         },
         {
            "newlabel":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "newid":26,
            "extraparam1":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "newlabel":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "newid":12,
             "extraparam1":null
         },
         {
            "newlabel":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "newid":34,
            "extraparam1":null
         }
      ]
   }
]

obj1.forEach(val=>{

if(val.data){
 //logic to modify the existing object
}

});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the main object without changes. You can do something like this:

```
const obj1 = [
    {
        "val":"type1",
        "removed":"N",
        "data":[
            {
                "label":"type1-a",
                "removed":"N",
                "dataid":16
            },
            {
                "label":"type1-b",
                "removed":"N",
                "dataid":26
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "val":"type2",
        "removed":"N",
        "data":[
            {
                "label":"type2-a",
                "removed":"N",
                "dataid":12
            },
            {
                "label":"type2-b",
                "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
            }
        ]
    }]
;

let result = obj1.map(({ data, ...values }) => {
    return {
        ...values,
        data: data.map(({ label, dataid, ...rest }) => ({
            ...rest,
            newlabel: label,
            newid: dataid,
            extraparam1: null
        }))
    }
})
```

This approach will return a new clean copy of the object.

But if you want to update the object. You can do something like this:

```
obj1.forEach(val => {
    if (val.data) {
        val.data = val.data.map(({ label, dataid, ...rest }) => ({
            ...rest,
            newlabel: label,
            newid: dataid,
            extraparam1: null
        }))
    }
});
```

Comment: If I have 10 extra property do I need to write each of them ? Is there any other approach to avoid writing all property again?

Comment: Where those extra properties will come from? Will be the same for each data.element?

Comment: no that is the outside object property such as val and removed.

Comment: take a look at my edit. Now you can see a `({ label, dataid, ...rest })`, that just deconstruct label and dataid because you want to change the object key, and *...rest* means all those other properties you don't want to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was about to use this on one of the function

Comment: If you can help me in this question.. it would be great. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707256/manipulate-two-array-of-objects-make-new-array-and-update-the-attribute-of-objec

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
obj1.map(data => ({label:data.label, dataid:data.dataid, removed:data.removed, param: null} ))
```

Comment: how it iterates through all objects?