# manipulate two array of objects make new array and update the attribute of object1 and add in the new array and modify nested object if needed

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I am trying to compare two array of objects and want to achieve the custom array of object by manipulating it.

It was achieved through following

```js
obj1 = [
   {
      "id":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   }
]

obj2 = [
   {
      "id":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "labelname":"type1-a",
            "id":12
         },
         {
            "labelname":"type1-c",
            "id":34
         },
         {
            "labelname":"type1-d",
            "id":36
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "labelname":"type2-a",
            "id":12
         }
      ]
   },
   ,
   
   {
      "id":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "labelname":"type3-a",
            "id":12
         },
         {
            "labelname":"type3-b",
            "id":34
         }
      ]
   }
]

const result = [...obj2.map(record => {
  const record2 = obj1.find(pr => pr.id === record.id) || {};

  const data = [...(record.data || []).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
      ...(record2.data.find(npr => npr.dataid === pr.id) || {})
    })),
    ...(record2.data || []).filter(pr => !record.data.some(npr => npr.dataid === pr.id)).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
      removed: 'Y'
    }))
  ]

  return {
    ...record,
    ...record2,
    data

  }
}), ...obj1.filter(pr => !obj2.some(npr => npr.id === pr.id)).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
  removed: "Y"
}))]

console.log(result);



expected result =

[
   {
      "id":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-d",
            "dataid":36,
            "removed":"N",
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"Y",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   
   {
      "id":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type3-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type3-b",
             "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But I am not getting the result which I am expecting.

I would like to map and modify the obj2 data if it doesn't exist in obj1.

for example, i want to modify type1,type2,type3 data object according to label, removed, and dataid instead of the newlabel and id.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. In your expected result you have in type3 a data value with the same structure of one of the obj2 data.elements (labelname). Which is the criteria? Because in type1 the type1-d is stored as label instead of labelname. Could you please give more detail?

Comment: sorry, I have modified it.. it should match with exact properties how obj1 have... basically somehow I need to use the previous question mapper function before comparisons

Comment: The function is if I remove anything from obj1 which is the default object while obj2 is modified object .. so I want result which compare obj2 to obj1 and check if anything removed or not in data object.... If anything removed in data object the respective property should be set to removed  'y'

Answer (score 1):

If I got the logic properly, it is not just simple as the issue of your previous question...

In your previous question, the ***data*** property of the default object was replaced by the ***data*** property of the modified object. In this situation, you have to add those new data elements of the modified object into the default one (if those elements don't exist) and mark as ***removed*** the ones that are present in the default object but not in the modified.

If you want a performant algorithm, you will need to have some considerations.
For example:

1. Reduce the source arrays (obj1, obj2) to javascript objects to avoid unnecessary double loops with *find or filter methods*, and decrease the complexity from O(n*n) to O(n).
2. Reduce the *data array* of the obj1, with the purpose of decrease the complexity to O(1) when getting a value, and avoid a *find method* which is O(n).
3. Set each data element of the obj1 as removed by default... and change the status only if it was not removed from the data object of obj2.

You can try something like this, it's quite more complex than the other algorithm but I believe that is one of the performant ways to solve this.

```
    let checkRemovals = (obj1, obj2) => {
        const defaultObject = obj1.reduce((acc, { id, ...rest }) => { acc[id] = rest; return acc }, {});
        const modifiedObject = obj2.reduce((acc, { id, ...rest }) => { acc[id] = rest; return acc }, {});
        
        // Basic actions in the default object
        obj1.forEach(({ id }) => {
            defaultObject[id].removed = !modifiedObject[id] ? 'Y' : 'N';
            
            if (defaultObject[id].data) {
                defaultObject[id].data = defaultObject[id].data.reduce((acc, { label, ...rest }) => {
                    acc[label] = { ...rest, removed: 'Y' };
                    return acc;
                }, {});
            }
        });
        
        // Update and add new elements
        obj2.forEach(({ id, data, ...rest }) => {
            // If it not exists in the default object, add it
            if (!defaultObject[id]) {
                defaultObject[id] = {
                    ...rest,
                    data: data.reduce((acc, { labelname, id, ...rest }) => {
                        acc[labelname] = { ...rest, dataid: id, removed: 'N' };
                        return acc
                    }, {})
                }
            }
            // If it exists, update it
            else {
                const mainID = id;
                
                data.forEach(({ id, labelname, ...rest }) => {
                    if (defaultObject[mainID].data[labelname]) {
                        defaultObject[mainID].data[labelname].removed = 'N';
                    }
                    else {
                        defaultObject[mainID].data[labelname] = { ...rest, dataid: id, removed: 'N' };
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        
        // Build the result
        const result = [];
        Object.keys(defaultObject).forEach(key => {
            const { data, ...rest } = defaultObject[key];
            
            result.push({
                ...rest,
                id: key,
                data: Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
                    acc.push({ label: key, ...data[key] });
                    return acc;
                }, [])
            })
        });
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Great. It solves my purpose.. is it possible if I map obj2 data property same as obj1 by using map functions mentioned in the previous question and then use only compare function?

Comment: Yes, it is possible! and also could be more clear, just consider to update the compare function to use those values for obj2

Comment: Can you please suggest me  3 seperate function so I can maintain reusability 1. Mapping of obj2 so it looks like obj1 2. Compare whole object and check by Id if it is removed or not 3. Check data object elements about removals..

Comment: I have added in question what I tried... But somehow it is not working

Comment: Can you please help me for Same

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/srkx3fq1/, you will find those 3 separated functions, but you will need a main function to do some common work.